# Multithreaded data transfer via an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

So, I guess that this has been answered before, but I couldn't find the question, so forgive me.

I have a rather basic chat client-server pair, of which the server is multithreaded to allow for several clients to connect at the same time. The server code looks like this...

```
private void loop(int port) {
        // Opens a port for connections.
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server running in port " + port);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

        // Listens for a connection
    while (onlineState == true && serverSocket != null) {
        if (cur_players < max_players) {
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println(clientSocket.getInetAddress() + " has connected to the port " + clientSocket.getPort());
                cur_players++;

                new Thread(new SocketThread( clientSocket, Chat.getOpenSeat() )).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here, what *Chat.getOpenSeat()* does is browse an array(boolean seats[]) through for an open spot in the chat buffer array (String buffer[][]) and returns an integer for the spot, then marking it taken. However, when I access the buffer array from the threads, the thread only finds the messages it has added itself. Below is the corresponding code.

```
toClient = c.poll(bufferSocket);               // Retrieves the top-most message from the seat's sub-array,
                                               // then bumps the remaining messages up in the sub-array.

if (toClient != null) {
    out.println(toClient);                     // Sends the message through the Socket.
    System.out.println("Message was sent.");
    toClient = null;
}
```

Curiously enough, the threads can access the *seats[]* array without any trouble, finding the currently active seats and correctly giving all the corresponding sub-arrays their messages. Here's also the bit of code I use to add a new message to the array:

```
public void offer(String msg) {

    for (int seat = 0; seat < Server.max_players; seat++) {
        if (seats[seat] == true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if (msgBuffer[seat][i] == null) {
                    msgBuffer[seat][i] = msg;
                    System.out.println("Message: '" + msg + "' was buffered for the Seat " + seat + ".");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So, how do I add Strings to an array that is commonly read-write accessible to all of my threads?

Just ask if you need to see more of the code.

Comment: first thing : when you reach the number of max_player, you accept loop becomes a very fast empty loop. probably not very good for performances.

Comment: not clear what the question is, and what the scope of each array is.

Comment: Is concurrency in the array what you're worried about? If so, consider making it `volatile`. See http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml.

Comment: @MarkTielemans Thank you, had you made that comment as an answer, it'd be the correct one.

Comment: @njzk2 That is simply because I have not yet dealt with it.

Comment: @Rogem : (ok. That was just something I noticed, but is in fact totally unrelated to your issue.)

Comment: the thing we need to see, here, I think, is the scope of the different arrays. where you declare them, how, how do you access it.

Comment: @Rogem: made it an answer, glad it helped :).

Comment: @njzk2 yes, I actually realized that just now. Basically, the arrays were declared in Chat.class, whereas my threads are the ServerThread.class. They are accessed through methods in the Chat.class. But, regardless, adding the `volatile` fixed my problem entirely. I wonder how I couldn't find it after googling for hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the array `volatile`, and it will behave concurrent.

More on volatile: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml.